# currency converter with the help of angular reactive form

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

Hi I'm learning angular and I want to make a currency converter using angular reactive form,I figured out the form itself, all the fields are readable, but after a request to the backend, the answer does not come, tell me what I'm doing wrong?

this is my html

```
<div class="selection-container">
<form [formGroup]="currencyForm"
class ="form-box">
  <div class="box">
  <input type="text"
   formControlName="amount">
  <select  name="" id="country1" formControlName="changebase">
    <option value="USD">US dollar</option>
    <option value="EUR">Euro</option>
    <option value="UAH">Ukranian Grivna</option>
  </select>
</div>
  <p class="title">  to </p>
  <select  name="" id="country1" formControlName="tocountry">
    <option value="USD">US dollar</option>
    <option value="EUR">Euro</option>
    <option value="UAH">Ukranian Grivna</option>
  </select>
<button (click)="convert()"> Submit</button>
</form>

<div class="result-container">
  <p class="title">{{changebase}} <span>=</span>{{result}} {{tocountry}}</p>
</div>
</div>
```

This is my request

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http"

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CurrencydataService {

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }
  getcurrencydata(country1:string){
    let url ="https://api.exchangerate.host/latest?base=USD"+country1
    return this.http.get(url)
  }
}
```

This is my logic

```
export class CurrencyReactiveComponent implements OnInit {
  currjson:any="";
  amount:number=1;
  changebase:string= "";
  tocountry:string="";
  result:number=1

  createFormGroup(){
    return new FormGroup({
      amount: new FormControl(""),
      changebase: new FormControl(""),
      tocountry:new FormControl("")
    });

  }
  currencyForm: FormGroup;


    constructor(private currency:CurrencydataService) {
      this.currencyForm =this.createFormGroup()

     }

    ngOnInit()  {
    //this.getcurrencydata()
    }

    convert(){
      this.currency
      .getcurrencydata(this.changebase)
      .subscribe(data=>{
        this.currjson= JSON.stringify(data);
        this.currjson= JSON.parse(this.currjson);
        console.log(this.currencyForm.value)
        if (this.tocountry ==="USD"){
          this.result = this.currjson.rates.USD * (this.amount)

        }


        if (this.tocountry ==="EUR"){
          this.result = this.currjson.rates.EUR * (this.amount)
        }


        if (this.tocountry ==="UAH"){
          this.result = this.currjson.rates.UAH * (this.amount)
        }
      })

    }
}
```

Please, help me to understand what i am doing bad

Comment: Please clarify *the answer does not come*

Comment: in the console, the response from the backend comes, but does not display on the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For explanation purpose I put everything in the component

Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vredis?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts) if you want to check it out

In your `getcurrencydata` you are not taking country into account you need to change it to

```
getcurrencydata(country: string) {
  const url = `https://api.exchangerate.host/latest?base=${country}`;
  return this.http.get<ICurrencyResponse>(url);
}
```

Then I would change couple things to use rxjs

In the component I would have something like

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable, of, switchMap } from 'rxjs';

interface ICurrencyResponse {
  motd: {
    msg: string;
    url: string;
  };
  success: boolean;
  base: string;
  date: Date;
  rates: {
    [key: string]: number;
  };
}

@Component({
  imports: [CommonModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
  standalone: true,
  selector: 'memento-stackoverflow',
  templateUrl: './stackoverflow.component.html',
})
export class StackoverflowComponent {  
  public value$: Observable<number>;

  currencyForm = new FormGroup({
    amount: new FormControl(10),
    originCountry: new FormControl('USD'),
    targetCountry: new FormControl('EUR'),
  });

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.convert();
  }

  getcurrencydata(country: string) {
    const url = `https://api.exchangerate.host/latest?base=${country}`;
    return this.http.get<ICurrencyResponse>(url);
  }

  convert() {
    if (
      this.currencyForm.value.originCountry &&
      this.currencyForm.value.targetCountry &&
      this.currencyForm.value.amount
    ) {
      this.value$ = this.getcurrencydata(
        this.currencyForm.value.originCountry
      ).pipe(
        switchMap((response) => {
          return of(
            response.rates[this.currencyForm.value.targetCountry as string] *
              (this.currencyForm.value.amount as number)
          );
        })
      );
    }
  }
}
```

In the template

```html
<div class="selection-container">
  <form [formGroup]="currencyForm" class="form-box">
    <div class="box">
      <input type="text" formControlName="amount" />
      <select formControlName="originCountry">
        <option value="USD">US dollar</option>
        <option value="EUR">Euro</option>
        <option value="UAH">Ukranian Grivna</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <p class="title">to</p>
    <select formControlName="targetCountry">
      <option value="USD">US dollar</option>
      <option value="EUR">Euro</option>
      <option value="UAH">Ukranian Grivna</option>
    </select>
  </form>
  <button (click)="convert()">Submit</button>
  <div class="result-container">
    <p class="title"><span>=</span>{{ value$ | async }}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.convert();
  }

  getcurrencydata(country: string) {
    const url = `https://api.exchangerate.host/latest?base=${country}`;
    return this.http.get<ICurrencyResponse>(url);
  } is it possible to take out this part as a separate file, I do it like this, but I get an errorconstructor(private currency:CurrencydataService ) {

  }

  getcurrencydata(country: string) {
  
    return this.currency.get(CurrencydataService);
  }

Comment: Yes you need to add export before interface, so that you can import it in your service. 

Then move getcurrencydata to your service

Comment: I updated on stacklitz if you want to take a look

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the forms value, you are using class fields, which are never assigned.

Change to and try again:

```
export class CurrencyReactiveComponent implements OnInit {
  currjson:any="";
  result:number=1

  createFormGroup(){
    return new FormGroup({
      amount: new FormControl(""),
      changebase: new FormControl(""),
      tocountry:new FormControl("")
    });

  }
  currencyForm: FormGroup;


    constructor(private currency:CurrencydataService) {
      this.currencyForm =this.createFormGroup()
     }

    convert(){
      this.currency
      .getcurrencydata(this.currencyForm.get('changebase').value)
      .pipe(take(1))
      .subscribe(data=>{
        this.currjson = data;
        console.log(this.currencyForm.value)
this.result = this.currjson.rates[(this.currencyForm.get('tocountry').value]
       * (this.currencyForm.get('amount').value);
       

    }
}
```

Comment: this.currencyForm.get('changebase').value) in this part i have error ((property) CurrencyReactiveComponent.currencyForm: FormGroup<any>
Object is possibly 'null'.ts(2531)

Comment: Remove the console log then

Comment: page crashes, same error